# Specifying type for generic function

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I have the following simple function:

```
private static Nullable<T> CastValue<T>(object val)
 where T : struct
{
    if (!(val is DBNull))
    {
        return (T) val;
    }
    return null;
}
```

I would like to call it while iterating over rows/columns of a data table like this:

```
var table = CreateTable();
foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
{
    foreach (DataColumn column in table.Columns)
    {
        Type type = column.DataType;
        CastValue<type>(row[column]);
    }
}
```

However, I am getting the following error:

> The type or namespace name 'type' could not be found (are you missing
>   a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Is there a way to call a generic function with a generic parameter that is determined at run time?

Comment: Uppercase T dude.. on this: `CastValue<Type>(row[column]);`. That is the cause of your 'type' could not be found error. As for your main question.. I'm thinking `dynamic` could be of help to you..

Comment: @SimonWhitehead - `type` is a `Type` instance, not the `Type` class. That wouldn't compile anyway since `Type` is not struct.

Comment: @Lee True, but as I said.. that is the cause of the error he posted :)

Comment: You do nothing with the result, so what is the point of "casting" it using your method?  How do you intend to consume the return value?

Comment: Your code doesn't _do_ anything.  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Check out this extension method provided my Microsoft: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360891%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't<sup>1</sup> because generic arguments are resolved at compile-time, while the column's type will only be known at run-time.

Since you're not *doing* anything with the result of `CastValue` it's unclear what you're trying to accomplish, but a cast should be unnecessary since `row[column]` should already be an instance of the column's data type.

---

<sup>1</sup>You can with reflection but I don't see how it helps your situation.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you need to make a none generic version of the function. If you think about it, if you pass in a wrong type, it will endup with a runtime error, so you don't get anything by doing it generic.